# Grouped Scatter plot not rendering all the data

Tags: pgfplots, plot, groupplots

I have a two data files that need to be plotted in two plots which I am plotting using the groupplots package in pgfplots. The problem is the data in the `hxe.dat` file is not all plotted. I have tried changing the values of the `Blue-1C` and `Blue-AC` Columns but still only three markers are rendered. Can anyone help me. The code I have used is below.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10, width=20cm}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{filecontents*}{hxe.dat}
Method Red-1C Red-AC Blue-1C Blue-AC 
Square 2.37 77.38 5.97 67.88 
Triangle 1.48 77.96 5.98 70.23 
Diamond 2.29 79.07 5.98 69.57 
HDiamond 2.83 74.17 6.04 61.87
Circle 2.03 76.29 6.38 63.60
HCircle 2.29 78.68 6.23 64.97
HSquare 1.71 75.48 6.23 64.28
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{bce.dat}
Method Red-1C Red-AC Blue-1C Blue-AC Vi-X Vi-Y
Square 2.37 77.38 8.75 75.56 5.97 67.88
Triangle 1.48 77.96 10.93 76.62 5.98 70.23
Diamond 2.29 79.07 10.06 77.78 5.98 69.57
HDiamond 2.83 74.17 9.42 72.78 6.04 61.87
Circle 2.03 76.29 10.15 76.50 6.38 63.60
HCircle 2.29 78.68 11.04 78.60 6.23 64.97
HSquare 1.71 75.48 10.63 74.45 6.23 64.28
\end{filecontents*}

\title{TestForGroupPlot}
\author{Satwik Srivastava (M21MA006)}
\date{March 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering
% \resizebox{0.95\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={group size= 2 by 1, horizontal sep=4em,},height=8cm,width=8cm,
    xlabel={SoE},
    ylabel={AUROC},
    legend style={
        at={(-0.1,-0.2)},
        anchor=north,
        legend columns=7
    },
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    xmin=1.0,
    xmax=14.0,
    ymin=65.0,
    ymax=85.0,
    yminorgrids = true, 
    minor grid style=loosely dotted,
    scatter/classes={
        Diamond={mark=diamond*},
        HDiamond={mark=o},
        Square={mark=square*},
        Triangle={mark=triangle*},
        Circle={mark=*},
        HCircle={mark=square},
        HSquare={mark=x}
    },
    % only marks,
    scatter,
    scatter src=explicit symbolic,
    % axis background/.style={fill=BG!5}
]

\nextgroupplot[title=(a), scatter, only marks, mark size=2.5pt]
\addplot [
    color=black,
] 
table[
    x=Red-1C, 
    y=Red-AC,
    meta=Method
]
{bce.dat}; \label{bce1}


\addplot [
    color=blue,
] 
table[
    x=Blue-1C, 
    y=Blue-AC,
    meta=Method
]
{bce.dat}; \label{bce2}

% \begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[green,opacity=0.20] ({rel axis cs:0,1}) rectangle ({rel axis cs:0.25,0.6});
\fill[red,opacity=0.20] ({rel axis cs:1,0.5}) rectangle ({rel axis cs:0.25,0});
% \end{scope}

\nextgroupplot[title=(b), scatter, only marks, mark size=2.5pt,]
\addplot [
    color=black,
] 
table[
    x=Red-1C, 
    y=Red-AC,
    meta=Method
]
{hxe.dat}; \label{hxe1}

\addplot [
    color=violet, 
    % opacity=0.4
] 
table[
    x=Blue-1C, 
    y=Blue-AC,
    meta=Method
]
{hxe.dat}; \label{hxe2}


% \begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[green,opacity=0.20] ({rel axis cs:0,1}) rectangle ({rel axis cs:0.25,0.6});
\fill[red,opacity=0.20] ({rel axis cs:1,0.5}) rectangle ({rel axis cs:0.25,0});
% \end{scope}

\legend{Resnet18, Resnet50, Densenet121, MobilenetV2, ShufflenetV2, Wideresnet50, EfficientnetB4}
\end{groupplot}

% Draw first "Legend" node using a left justified shortstack, position using relative axis coordinates
\node [draw,fill=white] at (rel axis cs: 0.208, -0.063) {\shortstack[l]{
\ref{bce1} Standard \\
\ref{bce2} CRM }};

\node [draw,fill=white] at (rel axis cs: 2.06, 0.75) {\shortstack[l]{
\ref{hxe1} BCE \\
\ref{hxe2} HXE}};

\end{tikzpicture} %}

\vspace{20pt}

\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:scatter}
\end{figure*}


\end{document}
```

Here is the plot that is rendered.
[image: Rendered Plot]

Comment: The values that are missing are just outside of the displayed area. Their *y* values are below 65 which is what you set as `ymin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You state `ymin = 65`, so values smaller than that are clipped away from the diagram area. Decrease this value, and they will show.

I would suggest the following improvements:

- Move the nodes that contain the partial legends inside the relevant groupplot. This way, you can use `rel axis cs` more efficiently together with anchors to position the nodes.
- Place the colored area on the background plane and define the coordinates using `axis cs` instead of using `rel axis cs`. This way you can use the real values from the *x* and *y* axes which might come handy here.

---

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, width=20cm}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{filecontents*}{hxe.dat}
Method Red-1C Red-AC Blue-1C Blue-AC 
Square 2.37 77.38 5.97 67.88 
Triangle 1.48 77.96 5.98 70.23 
Diamond 2.29 79.07 5.98 69.57 
HDiamond 2.83 74.17 6.04 61.87 
Circle 2.03 76.29 6.38 63.60 
HCircle 2.29 78.68 6.23 64.97 
HSquare 1.71 75.48 6.23 64.28 
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{bce.dat}
Method Red-1C Red-AC Blue-1C Blue-AC Vi-X Vi-Y
Square 2.37 77.38 8.75 75.56 5.97 67.88
Triangle 1.48 77.96 10.93 76.62 5.98 70.23
Diamond 2.29 79.07 10.06 77.78 5.98 69.57
HDiamond 2.83 74.17 9.42 72.78 6.04 61.87
Circle 2.03 76.29 10.15 76.50 6.38 63.60
HCircle 2.29 78.68 11.04 78.60 6.23 64.97
HSquare 1.71 75.48 10.63 74.45 6.23 64.28
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group size= 2 by 1, 
        horizontal sep=4em,
    },
    height=8cm,
    width=8cm,
    xlabel={SoE},
    ylabel={AUROC},
    legend style={
        at={(-0.1,-0.2)},
        anchor=north,
        legend columns=7
    },
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    xmin=1,
    xmax=14,
    ymin=60,
    ymax=85,
    yminorgrids = true, 
    minor grid style=loosely dotted,
    scatter/classes={
        Diamond={mark=diamond*},
        HDiamond={mark=o},
        Square={mark=square*},
        Triangle={mark=triangle*},
        Circle={mark=*},
        HCircle={mark=square},
        HSquare={mark=x}
    },
    % only marks,
    scatter,
    scatter src=explicit symbolic,
    % axis background/.style={fill=BG!5}
]

\nextgroupplot[title=(a), scatter, only marks, mark size=2.5pt]
\addplot [
    color=black,
] 
table[
    x=Red-1C, 
    y=Red-AC,
    meta=Method
]
{bce.dat}; \label{bce1}

\addplot [
    color=blue,
] 
table[
    x=Blue-1C, 
    y=Blue-AC,
    meta=Method
]
{bce.dat}; \label{bce2}

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[green, opacity=0.2] (axis cs:1,77) rectangle (axis cs:4.25,85);
\fill[red, opacity=0.2] (axis cs:4.25,60) rectangle (axis cs:14,75);
\end{scope}

\node [draw, fill=white, anchor=south west] at ([shift={(5pt,5pt)}]rel axis cs:0,0) {\shortstack[l]{
\ref{bce1} Standard \\
\ref{bce2} CRM }};

\nextgroupplot[title=(b), scatter, only marks, mark size=2.5pt,]
\addplot [
    color=black,
] 
table[
    x=Red-1C, 
    y=Red-AC,
    meta=Method
]
{hxe.dat}; \label{hxe1}

\addplot [
    color=violet, 
    % opacity=0.4
] 
table[
    x=Blue-1C, 
    y=Blue-AC,
    meta=Method
]
{hxe.dat}; \label{hxe2}

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[green, opacity=0.2] (axis cs:1,77) rectangle (axis cs:4.25,85);
\fill[red, opacity=0.2] (axis cs:4.25,60) rectangle (axis cs:14,75);
\end{scope}

\node [draw, fill=white, anchor=north east] at ([shift={(-5pt,-5pt)}]rel axis cs:1,1){\shortstack[l]{
\ref{hxe1} BCE \\
\ref{hxe2} HXE}};

\legend{Resnet18, Resnet50, Densenet121, MobilenetV2, ShufflenetV2, Wideresnet50, EfficientnetB4}
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much this worked like a charm !!!